# Permanently setting environment variables for VC command line environment

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VC command-line utilities (cl.exe), and I am getting annoyed by the fact that I have to manually run [vcvars32.bat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt%28VS.80%29.aspx) whenever I restart my console... Is there a way to automatically run a batch file on console start-up? Thanks!

P.S: I am using Visual Studio 2010 version on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the start menu under Visual Studio 2010/Tools or thereabouts; there should be a shortcut to a console that automatically runs the batch file.

Comment: +1, there is: "Visual Studio Command Prompt".  Just copy it to the desktop.  Give it a short-cut key.

Comment: That's not what the question was about. The point is not to have a shortcut and still launch console with that batch manually, but to have these variables permanently in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx

Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Visual Studio, point to Visual Studio Tools, and then click Visual Studio Command Prompt.